# not able to push message to sonic JMS queue in mule

Tags: mule

I have a scenario where I am reading the JMS message from queue and based on that I am firing SOAP call to retrieve corresponding document. However if SOAP service is not available or if its down, then I don't want to lose the JMS message that I read from queue. In this case, I am pushing this message to retry queue so that when SOAP service is up again, I can read the original message from retry queue and fire the SOAP call again.

Now the issue is that I am not able to push the original message to retry queue if SOAP service is down. Its going into the code block where I am checking for failure message and trying to push the original message to retry queue but its not actually pushing the message. This behavior is not consistent. Sometimes, it successfully pushes the messages but some times it not.

```
<when expression="#[xpath('//soapenv:Fault') != null ]">
    <set-payload value="#[flowVars['abc']]" />
    <jms:outbound-endpoint queue="${RETRY_QUEUE}" />
</when>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Any exception thrown when the push fails?

Comment: Any exceptions and example files that do not pass to the retry queue?